# python counting charaters without spaces in a file

Tags: python, file, character

how do you count charcters with out spaces? I am not getting the right number. The right number of num_charsx is 1761

```
num_words = 0
num_chars = 0
with open("C:/Python33/fire.txt",'r') as f:
   for line in f:
       words = line.split('\n')
       num_words += len(words)
       num_chars += len(line)
   num_charsx = num_chars - line.count(' ')
print(num_charsx)
2064
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words = line.split('\n')
num_words += len(words)
```

doesn't do what you think it does. In the loop

```
for line in f:
```

`line` is a string that ends in `'\n'`, so `line.split('\n')` is a two-item list, with the first item containing all the characters of the line apart from the terminating `'\n'`; the second item in that list is the empty string. Example:

```
line = 'This is a test\n'
words = line.split('\n')
print(words, len(words))
```

**output**

```
['This is a test', ''] 2
```

So your `num_words += len(words)` doesn't actually count words, it just gets twice the count of the number of lines.

To get an actual list of the words in `line` you need

```
words = line.split()
```

Your penultimate line

```
num_charsx = num_chars - line.count(' ')
```

is outside the `for` loop so it subtracts the space count of the last line of the file from the total `num_chars`, but I assume you really want to subtract the total space count of the whole file from `num_chars`.

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
num_words = 0
num_chars = 0
num_spaces = 0
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
   for num_lines, line in enumerate(f, 1):
       num_words += len(line.split())
       num_chars += len(line) - 1
       num_spaces += line.count(' ')

num_charsx = num_chars - num_spaces
print(num_lines, num_words, num_chars, num_spaces, num_charsx)
```

I've modified the line reading loop to use `enumerate`. That's an efficient way to get the line number and the line contents without having to maintain a separate line counter.

In `num_chars += len(line) - 1` the `-1` is so we don't include the terminating `'\n'` of each line in the char count.

Note that on Windows text file lines are (normally) terminated with `'\r\n'` but that terminator gets converted to `'\n'` when you read a file opened in text mode. So on Windows the actual byte size of the file is `num_chars + 2 * num_lines`, assuming the last line has a `'\r\n'` terminator; it may not, in which case the actual size will be 2 bytes less than that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try splitting the lines with a ' ' instead of a '\n'. As the '\n' should pretty much being done by the for loop.

The other option if you just want a character count is you could just use the replace method to remove ' ' and then count the length of the string.

```
num_chars = len(line.replace(' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
num_chars = 0
with open("C:/Python33/fire.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        num_chars += len(line.split('\n')[0])
    num_charsx = num_chars - line.count(' ')
print(num_charsx)
```